# Removing scripting notifications — App: Folder notifications FREE for Google Drive™

Tags: notifications

I have tried everything, yet the following notification for App: "Folder notifications FREE for Google Drive™" continues to be delivered to my email inbox.

I don't simply want to SPAM this email, because the fact that the script is seemingly still functional on my Google drive folder is particularly worrisome.

Please help me to remove this poorly scripted APP. I regret installing it.

> Your script, Folder notifications FREE for Google Drive™, has recently
>   failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown
>   below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your
>   setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.
>
> Summary:
>
> Error Message Count Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   12 Start    Function    Error Message   Trigger End 3/30/17 4:17
>   AM    prog    Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  3/30/17 4:17 AM 3/30/17 6:17 AM prog    Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  3/30/17 6:17 AM 3/30/17
>   8:17 AM   prog    Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  3/30/17 8:17 AM 3/30/17 10:17 AM    prog    Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  3/30/17 10:17 AM
>   3/30/17 12:17 PM  prog    Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  3/30/17 12:17 PM 3/30/17 2:17 PM    prog    Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  3/30/17 2:17 PM 3/30/17
>   4:17 PM   prog    Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  3/30/17 4:17 PM 3/30/17 6:17 PM prog    Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  3/30/17 6:17 PM 3/30/17
>   8:17 PM   prog    Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  3/30/17 8:17 PM 3/30/17 10:17 PM    prog    Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  3/30/17 10:17 PM
>   3/31/17 12:17 AM  prog    Authorization is required to perform that
>   action.   time-based  3/31/17 12:17 AM 3/31/17 2:17 AM    prog    Authorization
>   is required to perform that action.   time-based  3/31/17 2:17 AM
>   Sincerely,
>
> Google Apps Script
>
> Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not
>   reply to this message. (c) 2017 Google

Answer (score 0):

I found it similarly difficult to remove this script, as it doesn't appear in any of the list of Scripts at https://script.google.com/home, and clicking on the `click here` link in the email just displays;

> Forbidden
>   Error 403

Even though the error emails refer to a script, it seems that "Folder notifications FREE for Google Drive™" is [installed as a Chrome App](https://ez34.net/2015/12/installation-and-access-chrome-applications.html).

To remove this app;

1. In Chrome, go to `chrome://apps`
2. Right click on the icon for "Folder notifications FREE for Google Drive™"
3. Click `Remove from Chrome...`

**Edit 2018-02-01**
This didn't seem to work, as I am now also getting Authorization is required emails. I contacted the developer, and the advice is to perform the following;

1. Click on this link : https://script.google.com/create
2. Give a name to the script like for a google document
3. From the `Edit` menu, select `All triggers`
4. Look for a file name "prog" and remove it, click the cross.

The developer assures me that "Once that done all will be removed."